# Bin values based on ranges with pandas

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have multiple CSV files with values like this in a folder:

The GroupID.csv is the filename. There are multiple files like this, but the value ranges are defined in the same XML file. I'm trying to group them
How can I do that?

UPDATE1:
Based on BobHaffner's comments, I've done this

```
import pandas as pd 
import glob path =r'path/to/files' 
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=None)
    df['file'] = os.path.basename('path/to/files/'+file_)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
print frame
```

to get something like this:

I need to group the values based on the bins from the XML file. I'd truly appreciate any help.

Comment: There are a few questions here.  I would suggest trying to get the csvs into one dataframe as a good first step.  Check out the glob module and pandas read_csv() and concat()

Comment: @BobHaffner I can do that. On concatenating, it'd lose track of the file name. Wouldn't it?

Comment: You could create an additional field in each dataframe with the file name.  That would work, right?

Comment: then concatenate them

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. @BobHaffner

Comment: Haven't added the file name yet, but without it, I've done this `import pandas as pd
import glob
path =r'path/to/file' 
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=None)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
print frame` to get something like this:         `0    1
0  person1   24
1  person2   17
2  person3   98
3  person4    6
0  person2  166
1  person3  125
2  person5  172`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84756/discussion-between-bob-haffner-and-pam).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In order to bucket your series, you should use [the `pd.cut()` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), like this:

```
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['1'], [0, 50, 100,200])

         0    1        file         bin
0  person1   24     age.csv     (0, 50]
1  person2   17     age.csv     (0, 50]
2  person3   98     age.csv   (50, 100]
3  person4    6     age.csv     (0, 50]
4  person2  166  Height.csv  (100, 200]
5  person3  125  Height.csv  (100, 200]
6  person5  172  Height.csv  (100, 200]
```

If you want to name the bins yourself, you can use the `labels=` argument, like this:

```
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['1'], [0, 50, 100,200], labels=['0-50', '50-100', '100-200'])

         0    1        file      bin
0  person1   24     age.csv     0-50
1  person2   17     age.csv     0-50
2  person3   98     age.csv   50-100
3  person4    6     age.csv     0-50
4  person2  166  Height.csv  100-200
5  person3  125  Height.csv  100-200
6  person5  172  Height.csv  100-200
```